# How can i add users to a shiro.ini file in a zeppelin notebook

Tags: docker, shiro

i tried to setup a authentication process for my web-notebook in Zeppelin. I implemented the preset shiro.ini.template as shiro.ini. The problem im facing right now is how i could edit this file in my notebook to add users or how to do it in my terminal. I run it on a docker container. I tried to implement nano in the container terminal but its not working since i seem to have no root access to the Zeppelin image. How can i gain root access or edit it in the notebook itself?

Comment: Can the file be mounted/copied from local to the docker?

Comment: sadly not, since it cant access local files. Its running in the Zeppelin hosted image.